# Joomla add article & extra field values from custom component

Tags: joomla-3.x, articles

I have a custom component, from which I am taking my data & creating a new article with extra field values(from code). Below, is my code & attempt.

```
JLoader::import('components.com_content.models.article', JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR);

    $app = JFactory::getApplication();
    // Get the model
    $model = $this->getModel("lists");
    $newsLists = $model->getNewsList();
    foreach ($newsLists as $news)
                {
                    $articleModel = "";
                    $articleModel = JModelLegacy::getInstance('Article', 'ContentModel');

                    $data = array();
                    $data['title'] = trim($news->title);
                    $data['state'] = trim($news->state);
                    $data['language'] = '*';
                    $data['catid'] = '221';
                    $data['com_fields']['title'] = trim($news->title);
                    $data['com_fields']['source'] = trim($news->publication);
                    $data['com_fields']['page-no'] = trim($news->pageno);
                    $data['com_fields']['link'] = trim($news->externalurl);
                    $data['com_fields']['attributes'] = trim($news->attributes);
                    $data['com_fields']['downloads'] = trim($news->newsfile);
                    $data['com_fields']['date-free-text'] = trim($news->published_date);
                    $data['com_fields']['state'] = trim($news->state);

                    $articleModel->save($data);

                }
```

Actually, it creates the article correctly in the database(in Joomla 'content' table) but it only saves the single extra field value of 'title' ($data['com_fields']['title']) in Joomla fields_value table.

Code when I print $data;

```
Array
(
    [title] => unveils
    [state] => 2
    [language] => *
    [catid] => 221
    [com_fields] => Array
        (
            [title] => unveils
            [source] => 
            [page-no] => 
            [link] => images/news/unveils.pdf
            [attributes] => 
            [downloads] => 
            [date-free-text] => 
            [state] => 2
        )

)
Array
(
    [title] => Workshop
    [state] => 1
    [language] => *
    [catid] => 221
    [com_fields] => Array
        (
            [title] => Workshop
            [source] => 
            [page-no] => 
            [link] => /images/news/workshops.pdf
            [attributes] => 
            [downloads] => 
            [date-free-text] => 20.04.2015
            [state] => 1
        )

)
```

What's the wrong in foreach loop? Note : all the extra fields are already created from "Content >> Fields"

Comment: This looks like a well crafted question with a coding attempt, clear issue, sample data, and an expected result -- you are the kind of poster that we want to see more of. While you wait for support, please register your account  take the tour to earn your Informed badge, and perhaps add some details in your profile.